# How do I interlink the sprites with the character's movements correctly?

Tags: java, game-development

I'm creating a game but when it comes to linking the sprites with movement, it only shows 2 sprites instead of 4 sprites, stayed up and left with one sprite and down and left with another.

I've reviewed the code several times but I can't find any errors.
I expected the sprites to be well linked as I don't find any errors in the code, but instead it only shows 2 of the 4 sprites on the moves but I'm sure the prob is here:

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    if (dir == front_dir) {
        g.drawImage(frontPlayer[0], this.getX(), this.getY(), null);
    } else if (dir == behind_dir) {
        g.drawImage(behindPlayer[0], this.getX(), this.getY(), null);
    } else if (dir == left_dir) {
        g.drawImage(leftPlayer[0], this.getX(), this.getY(), null);
    } else if (dir == right_dir) {
        g.drawImage(rightPlayer[0], this.getX(), this.getY(), null);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's a debugging question, it doesn't have a good answer. The code looks fine, so now you need to challenge your assumptions (things outside the code):
 - does rightPlayer[0] really a sprite of player facing right?
 - does dir really change to right_dir?
 - is the code called only once, with correct parameters? Maybe it's called many times and the other times overdraw the results of this one?
You can verify them by moving code around and rerunning - e.g. if you think that the "left" case is executed, change the image there to rightPlayer, and see if it changes anything.

Comment: please provide a more complete example of what you're trying to do. for instance, a good practice is so separate your game animation in phases, so all drawings happen at once instead of being called by any arbitrary event and then invalitate the entire drawing context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about the question. Are there multiple characters facing multiple ways? Or is there one character that faces different directions? If it's the former, then make sure the sources are different.
If it's latter, then you're not using the right draw method.
You should instead use this draw method:

```java
g.drawImage(source,topCutX,topCutY,cutWidth,cutHeight,x,y,skewX,skewY)
```

If it's one character, then you should should make a *spritesheet* and use this method to draw the character. I would also recommend you have a class or a function for the characters. If there are multiple characters it's better to use a class.